# is it possible to use jquery after() and load() together

Tags: jquery

I want to make an ajax call but the data returned i want it inserted in the html after a tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will need a container for this:

```
$('<div></div>').after('#element').load('ajax.php')
```

Comment: The second call works as expected.  The first is not working.

Comment: Thank you for testing, I removed bad example

Answer (score 1):

The below code will help you enter the code after a p tag:

```
  $('p').after(function() {
    $('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
      alert('Load was performed.');
    });
  });
```

Comment: This method expects you to have a preexisting element with id **result** that will be moved into every p element and end up in the last one with the content from ajax/test.html.

Answer (score 0):

You would first have to use the load event and after a result (either success or error) of the AJAX gets returns you can append it to the page using after(). The after() would have to be used inside the success and/or error result.